# How or where can I register for blender competitions?

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, sculpting

I wanna further improve my blender skill and I feel participating in competitions will help. So I just wanna know where I can register for these competitions and what I should be aware before I do participate.

Comment: Competitions are fun, but not always happening... if you want to improve your modelling skills, try challenging yourself to model something you think is almost impossible (or at least far above your "perceived" level).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.